# Extracting most recent record in REPORT SELECTION FORMULAS GROUP. Crystal 13

Tags: date, group-by, crystal-reports

I am extracting information on medication requests. For each medication request, say in the last 90 minutes, I also want to display a date for any previous time a drug was dispensed for the same patient. In many cases there will be no such history as its the first time the patient has had this drug.

I cannot seem to both show the most recent dates for those patient/drug combinations where there is a prior date but keep the records where there is no history of a prior drug being dispensed.

I have utilised Report, Selection Formulas Group as has worked in the past with different queries.

{@DispenseDT}=MAXIMUM({@DispenseDT},{@RefDRUGPATID})

NB DispenseDT is a formula joining Dispensed Date and Dispensed Time
NB RefDRUGPATID creates a unique reference for each Drug and Patient combination.

This appears to work in pulling through the most recent dispensed date/time for each DRUG/PATIENT combination. If I don't do this I get the first (oldest) record.

However, when I apply this I also lose records. I think this is because not all the DRUG/PATIENT combinations being requested have had previous records so when the formula cant find a MAXIMUM it excludes the record entirely.

I have tried doing something like if isnull({@DispenseDT}then " " else
ToText({@DispenseDT}=MAXIMUM({@DispenseDT},{@RefDRUGPATID})) but when I try and create a formula and display this I just seem to get either BLANKS or TRUE or FALSE displayed, not the "MAXIMUM" DispenseDT. It doesn't like me putting the formula within SELECTION FORMULAS GROUP either.

So in summary I am looking to pull the most recent historical dispensing date for a patient/drug combination for each new request made. But where there is no history of a drug being dispensed I still need to see the new dispensing request record.

I am using crystal reports 13.

Comment: Can you add some information on your underlying data structure (tables)?

Comment: hi. What sort of information in particular?

Comment: I would like to see the tables where the current medication request and previous dispenes(?) come from.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment. I have actually resolved my issue by implementing a descending sort when "displaying records"